# jquery how to send json data to multiple links?

Tags: jquery, json, post

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.test.com/users/" + get_back + "",
  success: function(t){
    alert(t);
  }
});
```

I was wondering how can I POST to multiple links? Do I have to create another `$.ajax POST` or can I just add more `url` fields into the same POST?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it multiple times, one for each URL you want to send to. But there are shortcuts:

```
var urls = ["http://www.test.com/users/", "http://www.example.com/users/", "http://www.test.org/users/"]

$.each(urls, function(index, value) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(formData),
      dataType: "json",
      url: value + get_back + "",
      success: function(t){ alert(t); }
   });
});
```

We are putting all the URLs you want to POST to in a JavaScript Array and then using [jQuery's $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through them and do an AJAX POST to each one.

Comment: that worked. thanks. what if i want to change on the fly the `data: ` attribute also?

Comment: My answer will allow you to choose whichever defaults you like, and overwrite them as needed. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. You could build an array of JSON objects each with a data and a url property and iterate through those.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add additional mode fields. JavaScript object literals (e.g. `{foo:'bar'}`) can only have one value for each key. Browsers tend to interpret `{url:'http://example.com', url:'http://example.com/page2'}` as `{url:'http://example.com/page2'}`.

jQuery's ajax functionality only sends a single ajax request. The following code will let you create a default request object, and overwrite its members as you see fit:

```
function createAjaxer(o) {
  var defaults = $.extend({}, o);
  return {
    send: function(o2) {
      var instance = {};
      $.extend(instance, defaults, o2);
      $.ajax(instance);
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
var a = createAjaxer({
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { console.log(arguments); }
});

a.send({
  data: 'yar=5',
  url: 'http://stackoverflow.com'
});

a.send({
  url: 'http://stackoverflow.com'
});
```

This allows you to set sensible defaults. And the basic idea is reusable for all sorts of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You must do separate calls for each URL, try using $.each to call the same code multiple times.